# Callback not called in database .on method

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-firebase package, react-native and redux.
When I'm trying to initialize data by fetching tasks from firebase database. I'm calling async redux action from my react component's componentDidMount() method.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    let uid = null;
    if (this.props.sessionState.authUser) {
      uid = this.props.sessionState.authUser.uid;
    }
    this.props.fetchToDos(uid);
  }
```

And everything works fine on the first build of React Native app, but when I save and reload, for some reason the callback of my db call is not called and it keeps not being called until I completely rebuild my app. Again it worked fine on the first load of an app.

Here is the call to database:

```js
export const fetchToDos = (uid) => async dispatch => {
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  database.ref().child('users/' + userId + '/tasks/').on('value', snapshot => {
    console.log('INSIDE');
    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_TASKS',
      payload: snapshot.val()
    });
  })
};
```

I'm porting my app from the web and this code works perfectly fine with my web app.

Answer (score 0):

[This Github issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1498) seems like your problem, I think you should give it a look. Good luck!

Comment: thank you, I found a partial solution by disabling Live Reload and manually reloading every time or use Hot Reload instead.
Very weird bug